# Refreshing ListCollectionView sets the value of selected item in ComboBox to null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, listcollectionview

I have a view with a `ListBox` and two `ComboBox`es. When I select an item in the `ListBox`, the content/value of the `ComboBox`es is refreshed based on the value of the properties of the selected item. In my scenario, the `ListBox` holds a list of clients, the first `ComboBox` holds a list of countries. The selected item is the country of origin of the client. The second `ComboBox` holds a list of cities. The selected city is the city of origin of the client.

The `ItemsSource` property of the second `ComboBox` is bound to a `ListViewCollection` based on an `ObservableCollection` of **all** the cities using a filter. When the selection in the country `ListBox` changes, I refresh the filter to display only cities belonging to the selected country.

Let's assume client A is from Auckland, New Zealand and client B is from Toronto, Canada. When I select A, everything works fine. The second `ComboBox` is populated with New Zealand cities only and Auckland is selected. Now I select B and the selected country is now Canada and the list of cities contains only Canadian cities, Toronto is selected. If now I go back to A, New Zealand is selected in the countries, the list of cities contains only cities from New Zealand but Auckland is not selected.

When I debug this scenario, I notice that when I select B, the call to `ListCollectionView.Refresh()` sets the value of the city on the client A initially selected to `null` (put a breakpoint at the call to Refresh and another one on the city setter on the model, see code below).

I *guess* - although I'm not 100% sure - that it is happening because I have a `TwoWay` binding on the `SelectedItem` of the city `ComboBox` and when the filter updates the list to the Canadian cities, Auckland disappears and this information is sent back to the property which is then updated to `null`. Which, in a way, makes sense.

My question is: How can I avoid this to happen? How can I prevent the property on my model to be updated when the `ItemsSource` is only *refreshed*?

Below is my code (it's a bit long although I tried to make it the smallest possible amount of code that makes the issue reproducible):

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class ClientModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields
    private string name;
    private Country country;
    private City city;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChange("Name");
        }
    }

    public Country Country
    {
        get
        {
            return this.country;
        }

        set
        {
            this.country = value;
            this.OnPropertyChange("Country");
        }
    }

    public City City
    {
        get
        {
            return this.city;
        }

        set
        {
            this.city = value;
            this.OnPropertyChange("City");
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields
    private ObservableCollection<ClientModel> models;
    private ObservableCollection<Country> countries;
    private ObservableCollection<City> cities;
    private ListCollectionView citiesView;

    private ClientModel selectedClient;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ViewModel(IEnumerable<ClientModel> models, IEnumerable<Country> countries, IEnumerable<City> cities)
    {
        this.Models = new ObservableCollection<ClientModel>(models);
        this.Countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>(countries);
        this.Cities = new ObservableCollection<City>(cities);
        this.citiesView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.cities);
        this.citiesView.Filter = city => ((City)city).Country.Name == (this.SelectedClient != null ? this.SelectedClient.Country.Name : string.Empty);

        this.CountryChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.OnCountryChanged);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public ObservableCollection<ClientModel> Models
    {
        get
        {
            return this.models;
        }

        set
        {
            this.models = value;
            this.OnPropertyChange("Models");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countries;
        }

        set
        {
            this.countries = value;
            this.OnPropertyChange("Countries");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cities;
        }

        set
        {
            this.cities = value;
            this.OnPropertyChange("Cities");
        }
    }

    public ListCollectionView CitiesView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.citiesView;
        }
    }

    public ClientModel SelectedClient
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedClient;
        }

        set
        {
            this.selectedClient = value;
            this.OnPropertyChange("SelectedClient");
        }
    }

    public ICommand CountryChangedCommand { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void OnCountryChanged(object obj)
    {
        this.CitiesView.Refresh();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now here's the XAML:

```
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding SelectedClient}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Country"/>
        <local:ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Country}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.CountryChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Countries, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
            <local:ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </local:ComboBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="City"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding City}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CitiesView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

If it's of any help, here's also the code of my custom `ComboBox` to handle notification of changes in the country selection.

```
public class ComboBox : System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox, ICommandSource
{
    #region Fields
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(ComboBox));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CommandParameter",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(ComboBox));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CommandTarget",
        typeof(IInputElement),
        typeof(ComboBox));
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public IInputElement CommandTarget
    {
        get { return (IInputElement)this.GetValue(CommandTargetProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CommandTargetProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

        var command = this.Command;
        var parameter = this.CommandParameter;
        var target = this.CommandTarget;

        var routedCommand = command as RoutedCommand;
        if (routedCommand != null && routedCommand.CanExecute(parameter, target))
        {
            routedCommand.Execute(parameter, target);
        }
        else if (command != null && command.CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            command.Execute(parameter);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

For this simplified example, I create and populate the view model in the constructor of my `Window`, here:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Country canada = new Country() { Name = "Canada" };
    Country germany = new Country() { Name = "Germany" };
    Country vietnam = new Country() { Name = "Vietnam" };
    Country newZealand = new Country() { Name = "New Zealand" };

    List<City> canadianCities = new List<City>
    {
        new City { Country = canada, Name = "Montréal" },
        new City { Country = canada, Name = "Toronto" },
        new City { Country = canada, Name = "Vancouver" }
    };
    canada.Cities = canadianCities;

    List<City> germanCities = new List<City>
    {
        new City { Country = germany, Name = "Frankfurt" },
        new City { Country = germany, Name = "Hamburg" },
        new City { Country = germany, Name = "Düsseldorf" }
    };
    germany.Cities = germanCities;

    List<City> vietnameseCities = new List<City>
    {
        new City { Country = vietnam, Name = "Ho Chi Minh City" },
        new City { Country = vietnam, Name = "Da Nang" },
        new City { Country = vietnam, Name = "Hue" }
    };
    vietnam.Cities = vietnameseCities;

    List<City> newZealandCities = new List<City>
    {
        new City { Country = newZealand, Name = "Auckland" },
        new City { Country = newZealand, Name = "Christchurch" },
        new City { Country = newZealand, Name = "Invercargill" }
    };
    newZealand.Cities = newZealandCities;

    ObservableCollection<ClientModel> models = new ObservableCollection<ClientModel>
    {
        new ClientModel { Name = "Bob", Country = newZealand, City = newZealandCities[0] },
        new ClientModel { Name = "John", Country = canada, City = canadianCities[1] }
    };

    List<Country> countries = new List<Country>
    {
        canada, newZealand, vietnam, germany
    };

    List<City> cities = new List<City>();
    cities.AddRange(canadianCities);
    cities.AddRange(germanCities);
    cities.AddRange(vietnameseCities);
    cities.AddRange(newZealandCities);

    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(models, countries, cities);

    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

It should be possible to reproduce the issue by simply copy/pasting all of the above code. I'm using .NET 4.0.

Finally, I read [this article](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection) (and some others) and tried to adapt/apply the given recommendations to my case but without any success. I guess I'm doing things wrongly:

I also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829969/comboboxs-selecteditem-is-unexpectedly-set-to-null-before-actual-value) but if my `ListBox` grows big I may end up having to keep track of hundreds of items explicitely which I don't want to do if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bit redundant model. You have list of countries, and every country has list of cities. And then you compose the overall list of cities, which you update when selection changed. If you will change data source of the Cities **ComboBox**, you will get desired behavior:

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding City}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Country.Cities}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

You have a right guess about why the city is set to **null**.

But if you want to stay your model as you have described above - you should to change the order of methods call. To do this, you should use [Application.Current.Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588798%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property (and you do not need to change **ComboBox** mentioned above):

```
private void OnCountryChanged()
{
    var uiDispatcher = System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    uiDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(this.CitiesView.Refresh));
}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and they work. I'll go for the first one, it's gonna be less code and easier to understand and to maintain. However, I'd really like to know how come using the UI dispatcher helps fixing the issue?? I didn't debug the code to see what's happening but since as far as I understand everything was already running on the UI thread, I can't figure out why using UI dispatcher can help in some way...

Comment: Method BeginInvoke() of UI dispatcher will schedule method invokation on UI thread, so when UI thread will be free to perform some action, it will perform the action you have specified. So here SelectedClient will be selected first, and after the SelectedClient will be changed, the filter for the CitiesView will be applied.